# Configuring Netbeans code completion order

Tags: netbeans-7, code-completion

I'm using netbeans 7.3 with code completion feature and enabled 'Auto popup on typing any Java Identifier Part'

I'm trying to type

```
System.out.println("Some string")
```

So when I reach this point:

```
System.out.println(
```

it automatically fills

```
System.out.println();
```

which is top of the popup list. Though while I'm typing the previous characters, the first item in list pop-up list is selected. But not filled automatically. When reaching '(' it happens.

I don't want to completely disable the feature. Just want to reorder the items so that I can get what I want faster. Is that possible?

Comment: If you really want to control it maybe you could do a completition module https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html . However, it seems to be just to much code to do a simple thing

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check into that.